# Can this be done without an eval? (note: expression does come from a string)

Tags: php, eval, user-defined-functions

In PHP I can wanting to eval a string, which might call one of my user defined methods.

What I have is something like:

```
function convertToBytes($value)
{
    $number=substr($value,0,-1);
    switch(strtoupper(substr($value,-1))){
        case "K":
            return $number*1024;
        case "M":
            return $number*pow(1024,2);
        case "G":
            return $number*pow(1024,3);
        case "T":
            return $number*pow(1024,4);
        case "P":
            return $number*pow(1024,5);
        default:
            return $value;
    }
} 

$expression = 'if (convertToBytes("1024K") >= 102400)
    return true;
else 
    return false;';

$value = eval($expression);
```

I am wondering if I can do that without the use of an eval.

Comment: whats is wrong or what you need?

Comment: I hope this is a simplified example of what you are trying to do, as I cannot imagine a situation where the only solution is to create a conditional as a string then eval the string

Comment: call_user_func_array may be a better choice - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: What is wrong with the example? it works

Comment: Your current example doesn't warrant an eval. I believe this would have the same result `$value = convertToBytes("1024K") >= 102400`

Comment: that's weird, my example wasn't working but the above (which I just wrote free-hand) does appear to work. So, I would change the question if I could, how would you get rid of the eval()? For back ground I am reading a bunch of expressions from a file that I am wanting to "test" in my script. Does that help?

Comment: @RedBullet You _can_ edit your question. Not sure if you were aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. You shouldn't ever have to use `eval()` for something like this, when you can easily set `$value` to the real boolean value such as:

```
$value = (convertToBytes("1024K") >= 102400);
```

Comment: Except that that chunk of code ('convertToBytes("1024K") >= 102400') is a string...

Comment: Why? You should start from there, first.

Comment: Why from a file? What's the process flow look like? Why would that statement be in the file instead of just a value to use?

Comment: It is a data-driven test process, so the idea is one would change the validation rules by altering the data file. It may seem artificial, but that's the idea...

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet it splitting it up. So that it is infact something like this:

```
function convertToBytes($value, $type) {
 ...
}
```

so then you can do:

```
$value = (convertToBytes(1024, 'K') >= 102400);
```

Yourfunction would look like:

```
function convertToBytes($value, $type = "K")
{
    switch($type){
        case "K":
            return $value*1024;
        case "M":
            return $value*pow(1024,2);
        case "G":
            return $value*pow(1024,3);
        case "T":
            return $value*pow(1024,4);
        case "P":
            return $value*pow(1024,5);
        default:
            return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The function being called is part of the string. different strings might call different functions.

Comment: Yes, which is why I put another parameter next to it called $type. It would ultimately function the same way. That is unless you mean you are receiving these strings in that format to begin with?

Comment: What I was looking for was to have the string contain code which would be executed. So, it might have 'strcasecmp($value, "whatever") == 0' or 'preg_match(%<somepattern>%, $value) == 1'